# Saving ArrayList<Fragment> during orientationChange

Tags: android, screen-orientation, orientation-changes

I am using an ArrayList, which, well, contains Fragments. I need to save the fragments that are within that arraylist during orientation change.

If the arraylist contained objects of a custom type, like ArrayList which I define myself, I could make "ComplexDatadype" implement Parceable, and save it in onSaveInstanceState.

But what can I do with an arraylist containing Fragments?

Comment: Are the fragments are managed by a `FragmentManager`? IOW, have you used a `FragmentTransaction` on those fragments yet?

Comment: They are used within a FragmentPagerAdapter (I am using a viewpager), but I would like to know if there is a way to save them without using any kind of managers.

Answer (score 0):

> They are used within a FragmentPagerAdapter (I am using a viewpager), but I would like to know if there is a way to save them without using any kind of managers.

If the fragments are in a `FragmentManager`, the `FragmentManager` will manage their state already. In that case, you do not need to save the state of the fragments -- you need to save the state of the `ArrayList`, so that you can rebuild that `ArrayList` via `findFragmentByTag()` or the equivalent.

If the fragments are not in a `FragmentManager`, you will have to play that role yourself, asking those fragments to save their instance state to their own `Fragment.SavedState`, and you arrange to get those `Fragment.SavedState` instances into the overall top-level saved instance state `Bundle`.